# How to insert a file into AS400 through SQL statement

Tags: java, sql, ibm-midrange

I would like to insert a file that hasn't an extension. It is a text file without a .txt extension. This is my code:

```
public boolean setData(List<String> data) {

    SABConnection connection = new SABConnection();
    boolean bool = false;
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.connectToSAB().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO AS400.ZXMTR03 VALUES (?)");
        if (!data.isEmpty()) {
            for (String file: data) {
                File fi = new File(file);
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                ps.setAsciiStream(1, fis);
                int done = ps.executeUpdate();
                if (done > 0) {
                    System.out.println("File: " + fi.getName() + " Inserted successfully");
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Insertion of File: " + fi.getName() + " failed");
                }
            }
            bool = true;
        }else {
            System.out.println("Le repertoire est vide");
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error caused by: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return bool;
}
```

I keep getting a data truncation error.
ps:

1. the file ZXMTR03 doesn't have columns.
2. to insert such thing manually into as400 I write this statement: `insert into ZXMTR03 (select * from n.niama/ZXMTR02)` it works. When I write `insert into ZXMTR03 values ('12345')` it works.
3. I'm using JT400 library.

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert a stream file into a database table like that.

Assuming your text file has EOL indicators, you'd need to split it into rows to insert one row at time; or insert some distinct number of rows at a time using a multi-row insert.

Also you're wrong in thinking ZXMTR03 doesn't have columns, every DB table on the IBM i has at least 1 column.

Alternatively, you could copy, using FTP, SMB, NFS, ect. or even the JT400 AccessIfsFile class,  the text file to the Integrated File System (IFS), which supports stream files. And make use of the Copy From Import File (CPYFRMIMPF) command or perhaps the IFS Copy (CPY) command.  If on a current version of the OS, you might want to check out the [QSYS2_IFS_READ() table functions](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/6340189)